# Angular md-button not functioning

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, material-design

I'm trying to utilize angular material and it appears that md-button is not rendering correctly while other items like md-card are

I'm using node with express and formed most of the application structure with the yo generator provided by Mean.js. All of these assets are actually loaded when I inspect the page with chrome's debug.

Any help determining why md-button isn't working (Only the text of the button is loading) would be appreciated.

```js
//These are my assets I'm including
module.exports = {
  app: {
    title: 'Icon',
    description: 'Collection of networks',
    keywords: 'Node.js, Express, AngularJS, MongoDB, Data, Networks, Research'
  },
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  templateEngine: 'swig',
  sessionSecret: 'MEAN',
  sessionCollection: 'sessions',
  assets: {
    lib: {
      css: [
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'public/lib/angular-material/angular-material.min.css'
      ],
      js: [
        'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
        'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
        'public/lib/angular-material/angular-material.min.js'
      ]
    },
    css: [
      'public/modules/**/css/*.css'
    ],
    js: [
      'public/config.js',
      'public/application.js',
      'public/modules/*/*.js',
      'public/modules/*/*[!tests]*/*.js'
    ],
    tests: [
      'public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'public/modules/*/tests/*.js'
    ]
  }
};
```

```html
This is the content that isn't rendering correctly

<div class="container" data-ng-controller="HeaderController">

  <md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
    <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools md-default-theme">
            <a href="#!/">Icon</a>
        </h2>


    <div data-ng-repeat="item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position'" data-ng-if="item.shouldRender(authentication.user);" ui-route="{{item.uiRoute}}">
      <md-button class="menu-button md-default-theme" href="{{item.uiRoute}}">{{item.title}}</md-button>
    </div>
    <md-button class="menu-button md-default-theme" data-ng-hide="authentication.user" href="#!/signup" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">SIGN UP</md-button>
    <md-button class="menu-button md-default-theme" data-ng-hide="authentication.user" href="#!/signin" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">SIGN IN</md-button>

  </md-toolbar>

</div>
```

Comment: Assuming your module has the ngMaterial dependency and the material-design's CSS is loading properly, try removing the classes from the button and see what happens. Take a look at the CSS of the button through the console, see if material is anywhere to find.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because "class" AND "ng-class".Overwriting.

Try this : `<md-button class="menu-button md-raised">SIGN IN</md-button>`

AND this : `<md-button class="menu-button md-raised" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">SIGN IN</md-button>`